# Bring Window Buttons to Front

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml

I'm currently developing a Twitter application for Windows, similar to the Twitter client for OSX.

I'm using the Windows Shell Extensions library found [here](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WPFShell) to make the entire window Aero, and be able to extend beyond the bounds of the designated window location.

I want the window buttons (Minimize, Maximize, Close) to be shown over top of the grid with the white background. This is a functionality that I thought would have been built into Windows, but apparently I'm wrong.

The two images below illustrate my point. In the second image, I want the window buttons to take precedence over the white-background grid, not the other way around like it's shown.

Is there some kind of code snippet or XAML-snippet that'll help me? Has anyone else ever had this problem before?

[image: Window sized so that buttons show]
[image: Window sized so that buttons don't show.]

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon a simple, yet dirty solution. I just made a path to go around the outside of the Windows buttons, and set the background of the outside to white, or whatever background color I was using. Then I just pieced rectangles together to make it look nice.

Here's the resulting code:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="0" Height="20">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="1.0*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="105" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <Path HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="20" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Data="M 0,4.11334L 4.008,4.11334C 1.792,4.11334 0,2.27332 0,0L 0,4.11334 Z M 140,4.11334L 135.957,4.11334C 138.192,4.11334 140,4.11334 140,0L 140,4.11334 Z  " />
    <Border Grid.Column="2" CornerRadius="0, 10, 0, 0" Background="#FFFFFFFF" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
  </Grid>
```

And here's the resulting image:

[image]

Comment: +1 I like the idea, but some applications add buttons to the window bar. These buttons would still be invisible with this solution.

Comment: @dowhilefor Excellent point. I might have to address that issue in the future, if it comes up. If not, I'll leave it alone :P

Comment: yea they look better than mine. I need to learn this. what are you using wpf xaml etc? I'm new at this techs but I'm good at other things since VB6. need to catch the rest.

Answer (score 0):

you should hide your minimize maximize and close buttons and draw your own like described here.

http://winsharp93.wordpress.com/2009/07/21/wpf-hide-the-window-buttons-minimize-restore-and-close-and-the-icon-of-a-window/

Comment: See, but I really want to avoid doing that if at all possible. I would really prefer to have the default Windows buttons showing over everything else in the dialog, just because I'm focusing on making this app look native to Windows.

Comment: ok but you should keep the titlebar too if you want to keep native. do you have any sample applications which succeeds what you want? you can spy on them to get the needed WM messages and then use them on your own window.

Comment: haha I think I faked them :) look at this project : http://www.tahapaksu.com/personal/sandbox.rar